# Is there a more lightweight solution to read/write MP3 with Linux+Python?

Tags: apt, python, audio, mp3

This works very well to export a WAV to MP3:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
song = AudioSegment.from_wav("test.wav")
song.export("test.mp3", format="mp3", bitrate="256k")
```

but it requires to install `ffmpeg` which takes 338 MB with `apt-get install ffmpeg`:

[image]

I'm working on a small container, thus I'd like to avoid using 338 MB for this task.

**Is there a more lightweight solution to read/write MP3 with Python+Linux?**

Comment: Please avoid screenshots, that's just fugly.

Comment: Does https://www.pythonstudio.us/learning/the-lame-project.html help? :)

Comment: @tink It's as ugly as having to install 338 MB to decode a MP3 ;)

Comment: @tink Thank you for your answer. This solution seems to involve C compiling, etc. so it will require to install dev tools too (`build-essential`) and it will be big too. I'm looking for a binary that could decode/encode MP3 from Python in a few megabytes maximum.

Comment: You don't need to include the build-environment in your container ... ?

Comment: @tink No, I'm only using Python pre-built modules. Also this page you linked doesn't really provide a ready-to-use solution, I had a look, but it's not as simple as it looked, it requires some modifications in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure it will work, but I'll try it:

Go on https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html, select "Linux Static Builds", this redirects to https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/. Then select https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-amd64-static.tar.xz, do

```
tar xf ffmpeg-release-amd64-static.tar.xz
```

Then:

```
./ffmpeg
```

seems to work.

It might be possible to keep only one of the 3 (or am I wrong?)

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1000  63M Nov 12 02:45 ffmpeg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1000  64M Nov 12 03:05 ffmpeg-10bit
-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1000  63M Nov 12 02:45 ffprobe
```

so I think we can reduce the required size to 63M.